# Post Data in Android with Retrofit 2 Not WORKING

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

Hello I need Help I have tried to post data using retrofit2 but when i post the data is not sent to the database using the API which i have created.
1.i created a class where by inside that class i did create an interface for posting the data the class is called config.java with the following codes.

```
public class Config {

public static final String BASE_URL =     "http://p.eass.cloudapp.azre.com/";

public interface RegisterAPI{
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("register")
    Call<ResponseBody> register(@FieldMap Map<String,String> params);
}
}
```

2.I created another pik_join.java class which handle user registration when the user clicks register the following is the code where inside it i have implemented retrofit.

```
public class pik_join extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText pik, mPhoneNumber, piksiri, piknsiri;
Context ctx = this;

/*network query assistance*/

private Retrofit retrofit;
public String BASE_URL = Config.BASE_URL;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pik_join);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
public void onPikPost(){

    String mpik_jina = pikjina.getText().toString().trim();
    String mphone = mPhoneNumber.getText().toString().trim();
    String mpik_siri = piksiri.getText().toString().trim();

    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL).build();

    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("name", mpik_jina);
    params.put("phone", mphone);
    params.put("password", mpik_siri);

    RegisterAPI registerAPI = retrofit.create(RegisterAPI.class);

    Call<ResponseBody> registerCallBack = registerAPI.register(params);
    registerCallBack.enqueue(new retrofit2.Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call,    retrofit2.Response<ResponseBody> response) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score -1):

[This github repository](https://github.com/xiaoyaoworm/Prolific-Library) demonstrates usage of Retrofit 2. Hope that helps.

Comment: let me check it out then will holla you!

Comment: It didn't help @Mayur